# Authentication between docker containers in microservices architecture, bypassing JWT auth for internal calls

Tags: docker, authentication, microservices

I have the following docker architecture, orchestrated with a docker compose:

- *Service1*: Frontend application, react app
- *Service2*: ExpressJS server
- *Service3*: Django server

The three applications communicate with each other through HTTP API calls. There is no limit on who can call who. Every application is externally exposed

The user authenticates on the frontend application (*Service1*) and it resolves a JWT that can be later passed to every other subsequent call, every other service has then an authentication layer to validate the JWT calls.

My question is: **How would we validate calls from *Service2* to *Service3* without any user activity (without JWT)?**

This is required for crons or maintenance jobs.

My first solution was to create a docker network with a fixed subnet in our docker-compose, like this:

```
networks:
  our-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "172.100.100.0/24"
```

Then, in *Service2* and *Service3*, I allowed API calls coming from this subnet to be unauthenticated.
I worry this could be a security problem and wonder if there are any better solution.

Comment: Came here today to ask a related question. Will post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JWT token is typically *signed* with a *private key* belonging to the token issuer. It is a good practice that JWT-tokens as an [issuer claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.1).

A JWT-token can typically be validated in two ways:

- With a call to an [OAuth token introspection endpoint](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-lodderstedt-oauth-jwt-introspection-response-00.html) of the issuer - but this adds more latency
- Local validation with cached *public key* from the issuer - difficult to add logout functionality

If you use the cached solution, that does not add much latency, the JWT issuer must implement a [OpenID Discovery endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) including a reference to the [JWKS endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets) where the issuer publishes its *public key*.

If you use Kubernetes, you can use a sidecar with [OpenPolicyAgent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/http-api-authorization/) that does the token validation for the app. It is not so fun for developers to implement token-validation functionality in every app, so this is an interesting alternative. You can also easyli add authorization rules with this solution.

> How would we validate calls from Service2 to Service3 without any user activity (without JWT)?

When Service2 received the request from the user, authenticated with a JWT - it does the request to Service3 on-behalf-of the user, so it should pass the JWT token to Service3 as well - so that the Service3 can operate and only use resources that belong to the user, e.g. fetch from a database. This can be done without user intervention (until the JWT has expired).

> This is required for crons or maintenance jobs

For Jobs - that is executed on-behalf-of the user, it is typically required to store a JWT-token with longer *expiration time* e.g. in a database. Typically this can be revoked by the user, and typically expire after 3 months or so, and then the user may need to authenticate again (or more than 3 months - depending on your needs). It is important that such token has lower permissions, typically only the permissions that is needed for the job.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't quite answer my use case. I am aware of the JWT authentication methods and how to use it, but the question was how to bypass JWT authentication for API calls without user interaction. An OPA also assumes there actually IS a user to validate, while I need to make some internal calls without any user

Comment: I understand, and added a clarification to my answer.... also pass the JWT to the next service.

Comment: @NicolòGasparini I aslo expanded my answer for jobs.

Answer (score 0):

It is late but I think the original question is still not answered.

What I usually do in such circumstances is that I create a "system user" and perform the operations on behalf of that special user. This enables to log such activities with the same framework if you do care.

From a security standpoint, you will want to restrict what this special user can do. And if those things are sensitive you will want to use super extra care on how a client service (service2 in your case) get access to the special user credentials.